# GeoServer 2.23.1 CORS Issue

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, cors, upgrade

After upgrading to GeoServer 2.23.1 we are getting CORS issue. We are installing GeoServer within an ECS Cluster in AWS, Tomcat 9 is being used as the server.

We have followed the documentation and uncommented the following cross-origin sections from the web.xml file of GeoServer ( WEB-INF/web.xml)

```
  
   <!-- Uncomment following filter to enable CORS in Tomcat. Do not forget the second config block further down.-->
    <filter>
      <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>
```

The below filter-mapping section has also been uncommented.

```
   <!-- Uncomment following filter to enable CORS -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

GeoServer is getting deployed correctly and we are able to see all the layers with geoserver and also preview it.
When we call a layer from our application we will get the following CORS error
[image]

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxx.xxx.com/geoserver/xxxx-management/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=xxxx_management%3Axx_xx_xxx_xxxx&TILED=true&WIDTH=384&HEIGHT=384&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A135&BBOX=-8766409.899970295%2C3443946.746416902%2C-8453323.832114212%2C3757032.814272984' from origin 'https://xxxxx-dev.xxx.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Now looking at the browsers Network tab, the following headers are passed from the application

Request Headers
[image]

Response Headers are as below
[image]

Now looks like the response is not coming as expected but we are not able to figure out why.
Geoserver is getting deployed and we are able to login correctly to the latest version

[image]

Has someone faced a similar issue?

Comment: Error messages should always be posted as text. Images are not legible on all devices, and cannot be searched by others with the same problem.

Comment: @Vince, The error message is posted as text as well now.

Comment: This question does not feel like a duplicate. In the referred question the user has Tomcat and an Apache httpd server in front of that, but if I read right, this question deals with only Tomcat.

Comment: Im still facing would be really helpful if people can share their thoughts thanks.